# Probability of having $k$ empty urns after putting $n$ balls into $n$ urns

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, balls-in-bins

Assume that there are $n$ balls (numbered from $1$ to $n$) and $n$ urns (numbered from $1$ to $n$). At the beginning no ball is placed in any urn. Balls are randomly thrown into urns: Each ball is thrown at each urn with probability $1/n$.

**What is the probability that there are exactly $k$ empty urns?**

Comment: The labels for the balls and urns, incidentally, have no effect on this problem.

Comment: @Thomas: They do. For $n=3$, with urns and balls labelled, the probability of no empty urn is $\frac29$. With urns labelled and balls unlabelled, it’s $\frac1{10}$; with neither urns nor balls labelled, it’s $\frac13$.

Comment: That can't be true, @BrianM.Scott. That's only true if you ignore the conditions of the problem and treat results "2,1,0" and "1,1,1" as equal probability.

Comment: @Thomas: But if you ignore the labels, you **are** treating those as having equal probability. That’s precisely why you can’t ignore the labels, and why Ross’s solution doesn’t work.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, which part of the condition: "Balls are randomly thrown into urns: Each ball is thrown at each urn with probability $1/n$" am I missing? The result set is smaller - there are not $n^n$ different results - but each result is not equally likely.

Comment: @Thomas: You’re not missing anything about the condition. You just have a very odd notion (from my point of view and that of the OP) of what it means to say that the labels have no effect. They **do** have an effect, because if you ignore them, you get a different answer **unless** you modify the calculation so that you’re not really ignoring them after all.

Comment: No, the labels don't have an effect. The process is thoroughly described without labels, and the result condition (exactly $k$ urns are empty) is likewise independent of labels. The labels have no effect on the probability. Sometimes, labeling does matter, but here it does not. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Thomas: You’re wrong, I’m afraid. Look at Ross’s answer to see what happens when you ignore the labels on the balls.

Comment: That's if you ignore the necessary conditions of the problem, not the labels, @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Thomas: Evidently we don’t speak the same language. In my language, ignoring the labels on the balls means precisely what Ross has done and forces you to ignore the conditions of the problem. When you point out that the unlabelled possibilities don’t have equal probabilities, you are in effect putting the labels back into the problem.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If I toos $n$ coins, what is the odds that I get $k$ heads? That answer is similarly independent of whether I label the coins or not - it is $\binom{n}{k}/2^n$. Not labeling them doesn't lead me to a result of $1/(n+1)$ - it is a mistake to think labeling changes the result. It doesn't. Ross's answer is wrong, but in the same way that $1/(n+1)$ is wrong here. There are times when labeling matters, this is not one of them.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, it does. *Not labelling* in this context means that you’re treating them as indistinguishable.

Comment: No, you are still flipping $n$ coins. Whether labeled or not, that does not mean that they are not independent coin tosses. That's ridiculous - it is still $n$ coins. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Thomas: The fact that you can imagine the tosses as being performed sequentially implicitly labels the coins. Similarly, in this problem any correct calculation must take into account the fact that the balls and urns are individually identifiable.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I can flip them all at once or sequentially. I have a set of them. I toss them. The one that falls furthest to the left I count first. Etc. It doesn't matter how I count them. I get the same probability.

Comment: @Thomas: Once again, you’re identifying individual coins: *the one that falls furthest to the left*. You’re implicitly labelling them in order to get the right answer, because if you don’t, you won’t get the right answer. You may find my (and the OP’s) understanding of *labelled* as odd as I find yours, but please recognize that to anyone who shares it, your original comment is at best very confusing and at worst simply wrong.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I guess we'll have to agree to disagree. Which coin ends up on the left is random, so it is not "labeled." I realize that in a lot of problems, labeling matters, and thus for pedagogical purposes, a lot of problems in beginning probability fuss over this. But in this case, there is no need, and it seems to me that you are stuck in a beginners mentality of what it means for the urns to be labeled. The problem doesn't change if the urns are identical and the balls are identical, given the other conditions as stated. The labels are a red herring that does not affect the result.

Comment: @Thomas: I’m stuck in an experienced teacher’s use of language. And in this case properly so, given the OP’s comments on Ross’s answer. The fact that the balls and urns do have individual identities matters, whether you call those identities labels or not.

Comment: Again, Ross's argument is in error whether they are labeled or not. Labeling might make it easier to not make the error (although it didn't stop Ross,) and thus serve pedagogical purpose, but there is some pedagogical value in pointing out when labeling matters and when it does not, too. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: That was a useful discussion for me. It made me compeletly confused :) But, I think I am in the same boat with Brian M.Scott. @Thomas: What would be your answer for this question if you assume balls and urns are indistinguishable/unlabeled? The answer for labeled version is given below by Byron Schmulan.

Comment: @EmrePer The answer is the same whether the balls and/or urns are labeled or not. The key is in the statement: "Each ball is thrown at each urn with probability 1/n." I suppose there is a hidden assumption (whether labeled or not) that these are also independent events. The point is, the labels add nothing to the problem that are not already there in that condition.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: I understood your argument. What I meant was that how your steps would be with unlabeled version like Byron Schmuland did for the labeled version. For example, when we have labels, there are $n^n$ total ways to put balls into urns. It is not the same when they are unlabeled. But, you claim that the probability in question should be same. I am trying to see how your computation would go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Choose $n-k$ urns that won't be empty.
2. Group the $n$ balls into $n-k$ non-empty sets.
3. Distribute groups of balls into the designated urns.

These 3 steps explain the three factors in this expression:
$$\mathbb{P}(\text{exactly } k \text{ urns are empty})={{n\choose n-k}{n \brace n-k}(n-k)!\over n^n}.$$

The notation ${n \brace n-k}$ refers to [Stirling numbers of the second kind.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.

Comment: @EmrePer No problem! I love throwing balls in urns :)

Comment: If you love balls and urns, can you have a look at the other question I posted (sequential allocation of balls into urns) :) I think it is a complicated one. I would appreciate your thoughts on that one. That is the original question that I am interested in. This question seems to be a small step in solving the other question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  how many ways are there to choose the $k$ empty urns?  How many ways to distribute the balls into the $n-k$ urns such that each urn gets at least one ball?  For the second, think stars and bars.

Comment: My problem is that I can not compute How many ways to distribute the balls into the n−k urns such that each urn gets at least one ball since balls are also distinguishable? That is, (Ball 1, Ball 2 in urn 1, ball 3 in urn 2) is different than (Ball 1, Ball 3 in urn 1, ball 2 in urn 2). I see that answer will be: There are $n^{n}$ ways to put $n$ balls to $n$ urns. There are $\binom{n}{k}$
ways to choose $k$ empty urns. We want to place $n$ balls into $n-k$ urns
which can be done in $x$ ways. Hence, the result is
\
\frac{1}{n^{n}}\binom{n}{k}x
\

Comment: @EmrePer:  As Thomas Andrews comments, you can ignore the labels on the balls (and urns) if you want the probability of a given number of empties.

Comment: Well, actually, I am confused now. Let's consider $n=3$. Assume there are no labels. Then, there are 3 ways to allocate balls: 3+0+0, 2+1+0, 1+1+1. Then, the probability of emptiness for each $k$ is $1/3$? But, this is not true in labeled version. What am I missing?

Comment: @EmrePer: You’re not missing anything: the labels matter.

Comment: You are missing that the 3 ways are not equally likely. 3+ 0+0 has p=1/9, 2+1+0 has p=6/9 and 1+1+1 has p=2/9. The labels DO NOT matter. The logic is, for

Comment: The logic is, for 3+0+0 you can throw the first ball in any urn (p=3/3) but the other two must hit the same urn (p=(1/3)^2). For 1+1+1 the first ball goes in any urn (p=3/3), the second must hit 1 of the 2 empty ones (p=2/3) and the third must hit the remaining empty one (p=1/3). 2+1+0 must have the balance of the probability.