# Determining probability of selecting a certain element from a set using

Tags: probability

Let $A = \{1, 2, ..., L\}$ be a set of integers. I form $M$ subsets, of length $K$, from this set and randomly select $K$ elements from $A$. What is the probability that a certain integer is in any subset of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

I think the question that you're trying to ask is this:  Let S be a subset of $A$ with $k$ elements.  What is the probability that a specific element $a$ of $A$ is an element of $S$.

To answer this question, let's ask a different question first.  Let event $E$ be the event that $a$ is not in $S$.  What is the probability of event $E$?

The probability that $a$ is not selected in the first draw is $\frac{L-1}{L}$.  The probability that $a$ is not selected in the second draw is $\frac{L-2}{L-1}$.  So the probability that $a$ is not in $S$ is
\begin{equation}
  P(E) = \frac{(L-1)(L-2)\cdots(L-K)}{(L)(L-1)\cdots(L-K+1)} = \frac{L-K}{L}
\end{equation}

So the probability that $a$ lies in $S$ is $1-P(E)=\frac{K}{L}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the $m_j$ elements of each $M_i$ are chosen at random.

If the $m_j$ elements of each $M_i$ are unique, then the probability that any $a_f\in A$ is $\notin M_i$ is $1-\frac{K}{L}$. The probability that any $a_f\in A$ is $\in M$ is therefore $1-(1-\frac{K}{L})^M$.

If the $m_j$ elements of each $M_i$ are not (necessarily) unique, then this is a problem of partitioning. From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351190/probability-of-having-k-empty-urns-after-putting-n-balls-into-n-urns) question, and covering all possibilities, the probability that any $a_f\in A$ is $\notin M_i$ is:

$$P(a_f\notin M_i)=1-\sum_{j=0}^{K-1}\frac{{L\choose L-j}{K \brace L-j}(L-j)!}{L^L}$$

Giving:

$$P(a_f\in M)=1-\left(1-\sum_{j=0}^{K-1}\frac{{L\choose L-j}{K \brace L-j}(L-j)!}{L^L}\right)^M$$

Comment: If $M_i$ are not unique, then what will be the probability?

Comment: Deleted comment