# k balls thrown into k urns, what is the probability the 2 urns will be empty

Tags: combinatorics

I know the probability of no urns being empty is $\ \frac{k!}{k^k}, k≥3$
in order for two to be empty
I am unsure as to where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean how many ways to get *exactly* $2$ empty urns.

There are two possible sets of counts for the numbers of balls in the $k$ urns: $(0,0,1,\ldots,1,2,2)$ and $(0,0,1,\ldots,1,3)$.  For the former, you have $\binom k{2,2,k-4}=\frac{k!}{2!2!(k-4)!}$ ways to pick which urns have which counts, and then
$\binom k{0,0,1,\ldots,1,2,2}=\frac{k!}{2!2!}$ ways to assign balls to those urns.  Similarly, for the second possibility, you have $\binom k{1,2,k-3}$ ways to pick the urns and $\binom k{0,0,1,\ldots,1,3}=\frac{k!}{3!}$ ways to assign the balls.  To get the probability of having exactly two empty urns, add these up and divide by $k^k$: you get
$$\frac{(k!)^2}{k^k}\left(\frac{1}{16(k-4)!} + \frac{1}{12(k-3)!}\right)$$

The proof looks like it only works for $k\ge 4$, but it's actually valid for $k\ge 1$ given the natural interpretation that $1/k!=0$ for $k<0$.

See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351190/probability-of-having-k-empty-urns-after-putting-n-balls-into-n-urns) for a solution in terms of Stirling numbers.